# Tridion CMS 401 unauthorized exception | Accessing the CMS via a proxy

Tags: web8, content-manager, webdav

We have SDL web 8.1 CMS system.

This CMS is accessed in below two different scenarios:

**Scenario 1:**

---

Access (hitting the CMS url) without any proxy server in between
 - This works perfectly fine without any issues and we can see various parts of CMS(publications, content) loading fine

---

**Scenario 2:**
Access (hitting the CMS url) with a proxy inbetween.

To be more clear, this proxy is of our organization network only. When I try opening CMS, i get 401 unauthorized error for almost all URLs seen below.

[image]

**Header Parameters are shown below:**
[image]

In the response headers, you can see there isa **VIA** header added. **What setting i should do on the proxy to allow proper access ?**

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this [loopback](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/896861/you-receive-error-401-1-when-you-browse-a-web-site-that-uses-integrate) link.

Comment: already tried this one, but did not help. Any other possible areas to check ??

Comment: This is why you should copy the relevant parts of any URL you link to in your answer: that link is now dead :)